# How to make css grid height increase to accommodate grid gap?

Tags: css, css-grid

i'm facing this problem with grid where when i add a row-gap property the grid items will overflow in the bottom and cover other elements..how can i prevent this from happening? is there a way to make the grid parent's height increase automatically to fit the changes after gap is added?

i'm using react and bootstrap in my project..but to style the grid i'm using mainly CSS only

CSS

```
.items-grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
    row-gap: 3%;
}
```

REACT.JS JSX

```
<div>
            <div>
                <div className="items-grid w-80 mx-auto">
                    {itemsList.map((item) => {
                        return <Item key={item._id} title={item.title} image={item.image} />
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="w-90 mx-auto text-center my-5">
                <h4 className="d-inline">"Some text"</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
```

here is what i end up with, as you can see the last row is overflowing in the bottom covering the elements below..what can i do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Is your site publicly accessible? Can you give us a link to it?